# Org: Add front cover for LaTeX/PDF export?

Tags: latex, org-export

I want to add a front cover for my Org document which will export as a PDF (`#+LaTeX_CLASS: article`). I don't want to modify my `org-latex-classes` and apply globally.

I tried to add the following block before first outline of the Org document, but it will insert the cover under the contents.

Is there any way to insert a LaTeX block to generate front cover for an individual Org article?

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX latex
\newcommand*{\titleGP}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
\centering % Center all text
\vspace*{\baselineskip} % White space at the top of the page

\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thin horizontal line

{\LARGE THE BIG BOOK\\ OF \\[0.3\baselineskip] \LaTeX ~TEMPLATES}\\[0.2\baselineskip] % Title

\rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal line
\rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thick horizontal line

\scshape % Small caps
A number of fascinating and life-changing templates \\ % Tagline(s) or further description
presented  in a clear and useable way \\[\baselineskip] % Tagline(s) or further description
New Zealand,  2011--2012\par % Location and year

\vspace*{2\baselineskip} % Whitespace between location/year and editors

Edited by \\[\baselineskip]
{\Large JOHN SMITH \\ JANE SMITH \\ JAMES SMITH\par} % Editor list
{\itshape The University of California \\ Berkeley\par} % Editor affiliation

\vfill % Whitespace between editor names and publisher logo

{\scshape 2012} \\[0.3\baselineskip] % Year published
{\large THE PUBLISHER}\par % Publisher

\endgroup}
\titleGP % This command includes the title page
#+END_LaTeX
```

Comment: Just locally bind `org-latex-title-command` to include `\titleGP` which should be loaded in the preamble.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @ramus suggested, you can set `org-latex-title-command` to a custom macro and have it used in place of `\maketitle`.  If you set `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` to `t` you can do this per file using `#+BIND org-latex-title-command "\\titleGP"`, but Emacs will start bugging you about" unsafe variables". This will insert `\titleGP` immediately after `\begin{document}`.

Then you just have to make sure the `\titleGP` macro is defined in the preamble, which we do with `#+LATEX_HEADER`.  A complete example is

```
#+BIND: org-latex-title-command "\\titleGP"

#+LATEX_HEADER: \newcommand*{\titleGP}{\begingroup % Create the command for including the title page in the document
#+LATEX_HEADER: \centering % Center all text
#+LATEX_HEADER: \vspace*{\baselineskip} % White space at the top of the page
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace*{2pt} % Thick horizontal line
#+LATEX_HEADER: \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thin horizontal line
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\LARGE THE BIG BOOK\\ OF \\[0.3\baselineskip] \LaTeX ~TEMPLATES}\\[0.2\baselineskip] % Title
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: \rule{\textwidth}{0.4pt}\vspace*{-\baselineskip}\vspace{3.2pt} % Thin horizontal line
#+LATEX_HEADER: \rule{\textwidth}{1.6pt}\\[\baselineskip] % Thick horizontal line
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: \scshape % Small caps
#+LATEX_HEADER: A number of fascinating and life-changing templates \\ % Tagline(s) or further description
#+LATEX_HEADER: presented  in a clear and useable way \\[\baselineskip] % Tagline(s) or further description
#+LATEX_HEADER: New Zealand,  2011--2012\par % Location and year
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: \vspace*{2\baselineskip} % Whitespace between location/year and editors
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: Edited by \\[\baselineskip]
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\Large JOHN SMITH \\ JANE SMITH \\ JAMES SMITH\par} % Editor list
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\itshape The University of California \\ Berkeley\par} % Editor affiliation
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: \vfill % Whitespace between editor names and publisher logo
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\scshape 2012} \\[0.3\baselineskip] % Year published
#+LATEX_HEADER: {\large THE PUBLISHER}\par % Publisher
#+LATEX_HEADER:  
#+LATEX_HEADER: \endgroup}

* first section
some content
```

If you don't want to mess with setting `org-export-allow-bind-keywords` you could always just call your macro `\maketitle` instead of `\titleGP`, clobbering the old definition.  You'll need to use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand`.

Comment: Another question, the lines looks so ugly, any way to fold them?

Comment: You can put them inside a headline and fold that.  I usually call it "* Configuration" and but a `:ARCHIVE:` tag on it to make sure it doesn't get exported.

Answer (score 1):

In order to have the following document structure :

1. Cover page
2. Table of content (on a new page)
3. Begining of the content (on a new page)

You can do the following:

```lisp
#+OPTIONS: num:1 toc:nil % toc is nil to set \tableofcontents manually
#+LATEX_HEADER: ADDITIONAL PACKAGE
#+LATEX_HEADER: PACKAGE CONFIG
#+begin_export latex
\begin{titlepage}
DEFINE YOUR COVER PAGE HERE
\end{titlepage}
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
#+end_export
YOUR CONTENT IN ORG STARTS HERE
```